# adding multiple date sets and plotting the average in R

Tags: r, plot, time-series, average

I am using R to analyze multiple large data sets. I am trying to add a few together and averaging them to make a plot. They need to be added together with corresponding dates but the data sets are not all the same length/did not start or end at the same time. How would I go about adding them together while accounting for the differences in dates? My first option is to use an if statement, and say if date = date but I'm not sure of the correct process to call all file in the folder for comparison.

I have a script that plots one data set at a time and am simply trying to amend it to accomplish this new analysis:

```
library(openair)
filedir <-"C:/Users/dfmcg/Documents/Thesisfiles/NE"
myfiles <-c(list.files(path = filedir))
paste(filedir,myfiles,sep = '/')
npsfiles<-c(paste(filedir,myfiles,sep = '/'))
print(npsfiles)
for (i in npsfiles[1:3]){
  x <- substr(i,54,61)
  y<-paste(paste('C:/Users/dfmcg/Documents/Thesisfiles/NEavg',x,sep='/'), 'png', sep='')
  png(filename = y)
  timeozone<-import(i,date="DATE",date.format = "%m/%d/%Y %H",header=TRUE,na.strings="-999")
  ozoneavg <- timeAverage(timeozone, pollutant = c("O3"), avg.time = "month")
  timePlot(ozoneavg,pollutant=c("O3"), main = x)
  dev.off()
}
```

Here is some of the data:

> ABBR,DATE,O3,SWS,VWS,SWD,VWD,SDWD,TMP,RH,RNF,SOL
>
> SHEN-BM,05/01/1983 00,-999,-999,-999,,-999,-999,-999,-999,-999,-999
>
> SHEN-BM,05/01/1983 01,-999,-999,-999,,-999,-999,-999,-999,-999,-999
>
> SHEN-BM,05/01/1983 02,-999,-999,-999,,-999,-999,-999,-999,-999,-999

Comment: Providing a small sample of your data will help us understand your problem and provide a testable solution.

Comment: The data has been added

Answer (score 0):

Your question in not very clear.  Not being very clear on exactly how you would like add the data frame together and what to average, here is a generic attempt to answer your question.

To read multiple files in and merge them into I large data frame:

```
#read 3 files
basefilename<-"oa_test"
npsfiles<-lapply(1:3, function(i) {read.csv(paste0(basefilename,i,".csv"))})

#merge files into one dataframe
df<-do.call(rbind, npsfiles)
#fix date column
df$DATE<-as.POSIXct(df$DATE, format="%m/%d/%Y %H")
```

You could use the import function from the openair package in here.

No once you have all the data into one data frame, the dplyr package makes it easy to group the data by the various variables and perform descriptive statistics on the groups:

```
library(dplyr)
#group by DATE and average
ozoneavedate<-summarize(group_by(df, DATE), mean(O3))
#group by ABBR and average
ozonesumabbr<-summarize(group_by(df, ABBR), sum(O3))
#group by ABBR and average
ozoneavedateabbr<-summarize(group_by(df, ABBR, DATE), mean(O3))
```

Hope this helps.
In the future a providing some sample data and what you hope to achieve goes a long way on soliciting help.